# do class pointers themselves have class members ?

Tags: c++, class, pointers

I want to clear some concepts

1- A pointer can only store an address , pointer itself can not store data like any other variable can. right? (as the below code doesn't run)

```
int *myptr;
*myptr=20;

cout<<(*myptr);
```

2- if you create a pointer of a class say **FOO**

```
class foo
{
public:
  int numb1 ; 
  char alphabet; 
}

// this doesn't run
void main()
{
   foo *myptr ; 
   cout<< myptr->numb1;     
}
```

so my question is that would the pointer of class foo (***myptr**) have variables **numb1** and **alphabet** ? if not then what's the difference between a foo pointer and a int pointer (apart from that each pointer can only point to it's respective data type)

Comment: Your code will fail. It is pointing to garbage.  You still need to allocate a foo object and assign it to the pointer.

Comment: so is the first point correct that pointer can only store address?

Comment: I think you should refer to http://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/11683 @RazaUsman_k.

Comment: Yes - http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/pointers/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pointer has enough storage to contain a number which represents a place in memory. It is perfectly possible to use this space to store other information (the information still needs to fit into the pointer's storage).

For example you could store a long value inside the pointer:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    void *ptr;
    ptr = (void*)20;

    long information = reinterpret_cast<long>(ptr);
    std::cout<<information<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

You can [try it out here](http://ideone.com/wqAoe0) and see it will output the number 20.

---

Edit: here with a non-void type pointer

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct test{int a;};

int main() {
    // your code goes here
    test* ptr;
    ptr = (test*)20;

    long information = reinterpret_cast<long>(ptr);
    std::cout<<information<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That is valid only for a **void pointer**  ( that too when you explicitly convert it ) , pointers of specific data types can't store anything except addresses . right?

Comment: No, you can to this to any pointer, i just used a void pointer, but you can modify the example to any type of pointer.

Comment: but you would still have to explicitly convert the data so it can be stored in the pointer                for example       **ptr = (int * ) 20 ;**

Comment: @RazaUsman_k yes, because withouth that the compiler assumes that you are storing a pointer in the pointer :)

Comment: @RazaUsman_k its not a conversion, its just changing the interpretation.